# Customize Lock Screen Footnote without administrator assistance

Tags: ipad, settings, mdm, lockscreen

My iPad 6th gen running iPadOS 16.2 is **managed** by my organisation through [Meraki (Cisco)](https://meraki.cisco.com/platform/cloud-managed-network/) (MDM). They have quite recently added a **Lock Screen Footnote** (at the very bottom of the Lock Screen) and I wanted to customize it. I know they added it for a reason and I don't mind it really much but it contains my full name and I would like to only put my first name (or my initials)

While I was wandering in Settings in search of that parameter, I came upon the Shared Device Configuration Payload which contained the desired parameter. To get to there, I went `Settings > General > VPN & Device Management > Profile > Meraki Management > More Details > Shared Device Configuration Payload > Lock Screen Footnote`.

[image: following steps above (Settings > General > VPN & Device Management > Profile > Meraki Management > More Details > Shared Device Configuration Payload > Lock Screen Footnote)]

But, I was not able to edit that footnote (quite comprehensible). I have prospected and fell upon [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/lockscreenmessage) Apple Developers documentation page about the Lock Screen Message but it did not bring me far since it was only talking about the different available options for administrators to configure.

I have also found [this](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/deployment/dep3fbb42e89/web) Apple Support article which stated that the Lock Screen Footnote was available for :

> iPhone and iPad devices enrolled in a mobile device management (MDM) solution.

Since this feature is available for iPad devices enrolled in a MDM solution as I am, is it possible for me (not admin) to modify that parameter without any help from my organisation?

Comment: Your last paragraph actually answers your question...

Comment: Not really, it might just as well be possible for me since I have the ability to see this setting, @nohillside

Comment: Genuine curiosity... do you put as much effort into your studies as you do trying to circumvent and solve non-technical and non-problematic institutional policy driven measures?  You've answered your own question in your question.  Now, if circumventing MDM was so easy, why would any org spend the time and resources (people and money) to implement it?

Comment: @Allan I do. And I am not trying to circumvent anything here, I want to keep my privacy by not letting anybody see my full last name (quite long) because I don't use it at where I am normally (plus it wouldn't be of any help since no one knows it). This name is only for official and important documents, I only use a part of this name elsewhere. I can ask them to change that but I think they would not accept because if they do it for me, they will need to do it for everyone and that won't be possible I think (plus they are extremely slow at doing things - 2 days to change a protection screen!).

Comment: @Allan **Advice request** : I have another question about the meaning of some parameter linked with MDM, do I post another question, a comment or do I make it an edit to this question? (The only link is that it's about MDM) Thanks!

Comment: If you think you have a valid and legal reason to change it, approach the admins with your concern. At the moment, the only person who knows of this name is you, (and the automated process which assigned it to the iPad.) Somebody else who may find it if it is mislaid, lost or stolen will know it, too, but does your name need to be kept secret? Are you in a witness protection program, or royalty, or from a political or affluent family?

Comment: @IconDaemon Well, would you like to have someone turn up and see your name (which is explicitly shown)? I would not. It is not that I *need* to keep it not-much know, it is more because I don't want some random guy to show up and note my name somewhere and maybe search it on the Internet and find my profiles on various sites and networks and stalk me (slightly paranoiac ik). Also, it is not only me who knows it, there's the people who read my official or important docs (org admins for eg.) but since it's not possibly a person with bad intentions, it's alright.

Comment: This name can only be seen on the lock screen in very tiny type, correct? How many people, other than you, will actually see the lock screen under normal circumstances? You yourself indicate your motivation, paranoia, in wanting the name obscured. Embrace the anonymity you need to maintain by carefully managing access to the iPad from others. If you are careful enough in other aspects of your life to shield this name from others, keeping this lock screen name hidden should be easy in all but the most extreme circumstances.

Comment: That info is there not for you, but for the admins to identify the device as it accesses  resources and locations.  It shows on the lock screen to actually thwart theft and aid in recovery.  If someone else is in possession of your device, it's pretty much next to impossible for them to say "I didn't know this wasn't mine."

Comment: As for you next MDM question...what research did you do thus far?  If you can't find your answer and it is something that can be practically answered, post another question.

Comment: @Allan I completely agree with your statement, but it seems that you didn't quite understand what I was trying to modify here. I am trying to reduce my name that very few people know and will say that it's mine to a name much more widely known (in my org at least). I am *not* trying to remove my name from that footnote.

Comment: @IconDaemon Same here, all of that is only to make my iPad more recognizable and therefore to be sure to find it back if I lose it.

Comment: @Allan Never mind I found the answer for the other question, it was about some parameter called Check Out which was enabled for me, I've seen it meant that the profile could be removed from my device at some point (in may according to my org). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can't.

From the [Apple Developers documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/lockscreenmessage) link given in the question, it is stated that "This payload allows ***administrators*** to specify optional text displayed in the login window and Lock screen", this means that only administrators can modify that setting.

Note that I asked the admins and they miraculously accepted, so it's now completely solved.